# i am unable to mapDispatchToProps in the redux

Tags: react-redux

i am unable to dispatch it..
getting below error " AnswerButton.jsx:14 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.changeAnswer is not a function"

```
import * as React from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {isUndefined} from 'lodash';
import {changeAnswer} from '../../../actions/LoadRiskActionCreators';

require('./style.scss');

export class AnswerButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.updateAnswer = this.updateAnswer.bind(this);
    }
    updateAnswer(answer){
       this.props.changeAnswer(this.props.questionId ,answer);
    }
    render() {
        const {answer, questionId} = this.props;
        return <div className="toggle-switch">
            <span className={`switch${!isUndefined(answer) ? (answer ? ' active' : ' inactive') : ""}`}
                  onClick={() => this.updateAnswer(true)}>Yes</span>
            <span className={`switch${!isUndefined(answer) ? (answer ? ' inactive' : ' active') : ""}`}
                  onClick={() => this.updateAnswer(false)}>No</span>
        </div>
    }
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    changeAnswer: (id, answer) => dispatch(changeAnswer(id, answer)),
});

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(AnswerButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create mapStateToProps function and put it before mapDispatchToProps:

```
export const mapStateToProps = () => ({});

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    changeAnswer: (id, answer) => dispatch(changeAnswer(id, answer)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AnswerButton);
```

Comment: sorry. it's not the problem. i tried. it's not working

Comment: Can you add your LoadRiskActionCreators?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, at my answer. I will fix, try again please

Comment: or just use `null` instead of `mapStateToProps`

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `connect` is the `mapStateToProps` function.
If you don't need it, you must pass null as first argument:

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AnswerButton);
```

Since the name of your action on the props and the name of your action creator are the same and accept the same params, you can use the shorthand version of mapDispatchToProps:

```
export default connect(null, { changeAnswer })(AnswerButton);
```